# Passing class object by 'property get' in a parent class does not affect the nested class object

Tags: excel, vba

I have this hierarchy of classes which are defined as follows

cQuestion:

```
Private pText As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
pText = ""
End Sub

Property Let Text(T As String)
    pText = T
End Property

Property Get Text() As String
    Text = pText
End Property
```

cQuestionList:

```
Private pQList() As New cQuestion
Private pListLen As Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pListLen = 0
End Sub

Public Sub AddEnd(Q As String)
    pListLen = pListLen + 1
    ReDim Preserve pQList(1 To pListLen)
    pQList(pListLen).Text = Q
End Sub

Public Function Format() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    If pListLen = 0 Then
        FormatList = "There are no questions in this category" + vbNewLine
    Else
        FormatList = "Questions:" + vbNewLine
        For i = 1 To pListLen
            FormatList = FormatList + "• " + pQList(i).Text + vbNewLine
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

cCategory:

```
Private pName As String
Private pQList As New cQuestionList

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pName = ""
End Sub

Property Get QuestionList() As cQuestionList
    Set QuestionList = pQList
End Property

Property Let Name(N As String)
    pName = N
End Property

Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
```

When I attempt to call `Category.QuestionList.AddEnd "Question Here"`,
it does not throw any errors. However when I subsequently call `MsgBox Category.QuestionList.Format` I get a blank message box. I am not sure how this ends up blank, seeing as Format should always be returning text. What is it that I am doing wrong here? I have looked at other examples of passing class objects by let and get within a parent class, and cannot see how what I am doing is different. Any suggestions?

Example Code:

```
Dim C as New cCategory
C.QuestionList.AddEnd "A Question"
C.QuestionList.AddEnd "Another Question"
MsgBox C.QuestionList.Format
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `Option Explicit` at the top of each module and you'll see the problem immediately:

```
Public Function Format() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    If pListLen = 0 Then
        FormatList = "There are no questions in this category" + vbNewLine
           '^^^^ Variable not defined.
    Else
        FormatList = "Questions:" + vbNewLine
        For i = 1 To pListLen
            FormatList = FormatList + "• " + pQList(i).Text + vbNewLine
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

You either need to change `Public Function Format() As String` to `Public Function FormatList() As String` or change the `FormatList` assignments to `Format`.

I'd personally go with the `FormatList` naming to avoid collisions with the `Format` function.